Why does the fixed point locus of a circle action always have even codimension
So I'm studying equivariant cohomology, and I am in particular interested in the case where there is a $U(1)$ action on a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$. This is generated by some vector field $\xi\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$. The fixed points of this action are given by the set of points such that $\langle\xi,\xi\rangle=0$, where $\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product defined by the metric on $\mathcal M$. The claim is that this fixed point set is always of even codimension, but I do not understand why that must be the case.
